# Button not remaining disabled after submitting form

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am attempting to disable a button using an external JavaScript - activated by a submit button

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Join Email List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Radio_Button.css">
        <script src="Radio_Button.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <section>
        <h1>Fun with Radio Buttonst</h1>
        <form id="email_form" name="email_form" method="get">
            <input type="radio" name="food1" id="cake1" value="cake" > Cake <br>
            <input type="radio" name= "food2"id="muffns1"value="muffins" > Muffins   <br>
            <input type="radio" name= "food3"id="donuts1" value="donuts1" > hello   <br>
            <input type="radio" name="food4"  id="food1"  value="cookies" > Cookies<br>
            <input type="submit" id="drink_selection" value="Process Drink Selection" onclick = "join_list()">
            <br>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript is as follows

```
var getsElement = function (id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
};
var join_list = function () {

    getsElement("cake1").disabled = true;
    getsElement("cake1").parentElement.disabled = true;
};
```

I can see the button disable when I watch the code but when the HTML reappears for user access the button is not disabled.

Comment: what do you mean? you mean when you open the file again, it is not disabled? With your javascript code, you are only editing the disabled state of that radio button in your current browser session. To keep it disabled in future sessions, you will need some server side code.

Comment: "to keep it disabled in future sessions, you will need some server side code."

He could always store the state using HTML5 localStorage to store the state during that session and recall it on page reload. You do not necessarily have to utilize server side scripting.

Comment: I think that his problem is not keep the state of radio buttons (His code initially doesn't work)

Answer (score 4):

Your button reload the page, so your JS is missing. Also you should change your var join_list (scope var problems if you use this var in other functions like `window.onload`) to function.

So your code should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Join Email List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Radio_Button.css">
        <script src="Radio_Button.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
            <h1>Fun with Radio Buttonst</h1>
            <input type="radio" name="food1" id="cake1" value="cake"> Cake
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="food2" id="muffns1" value="muffins"> Muffins
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="food3" id="donuts1" value="donuts1"> hello
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="food4" id="food1" value="cookies"> Cookies
            <br>

            <input type="submit" id="drink_selection" value="Process Drink Selection" onclick="join_list()">

        </section>
    </body>


</html>
```

JavaScript

```
        var getsElement = function(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        };

        function join_list() {
            getsElement("cake1").disabled = true;
            getsElement("cake1").parentElement.disabled = true;

        };
```

Answer (score 2):

When you click submit, the page reloads. Any attributes you added via JS before the page reload will be set back to default.

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the input type to button rather than submit type.   My code works now.  Thanks.